# Submit tow forms with jquery rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Ok my issue is simple, i have two very, very similar forms on one view, only the id makes the difference:

```
<table width="100%">
<tr>
<%= form_for ([@patient, @patient.treatments.build]),:html => { :id => "my_form2" } do |f|%>
<th><%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.find(:all), :id, :typ %></th>
<th><%= f.text_field :content %></th>
<th><%= f.hidden_field :note, :id => "canvascontent" %></th>
<th><%= f.text_field :day, :value => Date.today %></th>
<th><input type="button" value="Speichern" class = "btn btn-small btn-primary" id = "button1" onclick="sketch.toDataURL()"></th>
<th><input type="button" onclick="sketch.clearRecording()" class="btn btn-small btn-danger" value="Löschen"></th>
<% end %>
</tr>
</table>

<table width="100%">
<tr>
<%= form_for ([@patient, @patient.treatments.build]),:html => { :id => "my_form1" } do |f|%>
<th><%= f.hidden_field :category_id, :value => findems(Ebm) %></th>
<th><%= f.hidden_field :content , :id => "inputbox"%></th>
<th><%= f.hidden_field :day, :value => Date.today %></th>
<% end %>
</tr>
</table>
```

And i want to trigger the submit of both with only one submit button, so i created an button:

```
<input type="button" value="Speichern" class = "btn btn-small btn-primary" id = "button1" onclick="sketch.toDataURL()"
```

And to trigger the submit of the both forms at the same time an jquery function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#button1").click(function(){
$('#my_form1').trigger('submit');
$('#my_form2').trigger('submit');
});
```

But it wont work, rails always only saves that form that is first triggerd in my function, in this case #my_form1. I think my controller is to blame because after the first is saved it redirects to another site so that the second form isnt saved. But im Rails beginner and dont know how to ovewerite this behaviour. My controller:

```
    def create
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:patient_id])
    @treatment = @patient.treatments.create(params[:treatment])
    redirect_to patient_path(@patient)
    end
```

I tried to simply remove the last line of my controller but then i get the error:

```
 Missing template treatments/create,
```

Comment: It looks like you need nested model form here. Check out this railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised Also you might benefit from this http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, I'm not really sure why you would want to submit those two forms separately... If you really want to go that way though, you could pass all your needed parameters with your first form and then use those within your controller.

With those params in hands, you can do anything you want with them, including building another @patient from your controller for example.

From you code, I see you're using `params[:treatment]` and `params[:patient_id]` but I don't see those params in your `#my_form1` form. How are those passed?